# Enable HTML inside a literal

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, richtext

I have this literal which fetches text from a database (and the text can be modified). I want it to display the HTML-tags in the text as html to keep the formatting however it encloses the fetched text in quotation marks. It makes the HTML not displaying the way it is supposed to. I've also tried to use tags and the innerHtml property too. Javascript has also been tried to remove the specific quotation marks. How do I accomplished what I want?

I no this is not a safe way to do it but it is a complete close environment where the few users are incapable of exploiting it.

**EDIT:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
    {
        p = new Post();
        p.ID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
        p.fetch();
        headerPost.Text = p.Header;
        txtPost.Text = p.FormattedText + "<p>" + p.Author + ", " + p.TimePosted.ToShortDateString() + "</p>";
        Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("_postid", p.ID.ToString()));
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("Diary.aspx");
    }

    if (Roles.IsUserInRole(User.Identity.Name, "Admin") || p.Author == User.Identity.Name)
    {
        editButton.Visible = true;
        deleteButton.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

It is the txtPost which refers to the literal.

In this case the p.Header is just the headline of the page in the diary.
p.FormattedText is in this case equal to "Kære alle`<div></div><div></div><div>`Velkommen til Hellebo's dagbogssider. `</div><div>`Her kan der skrives om stort og småt, om vinter og sommer og af ældre og unge.`</div>`"

(Written in Danish)

Comment: Can you add some code?

Comment: Without isolated and reproduceable problem code nobody can help you

Comment: We don't know what's the value of p.Header or p.FormattedText, and I think there is a problem since Literal control just renders Text property

Comment: did you try to put that formatted text in simple html file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. The formatted text was parsed through a BBCode parser which made the whole thing screw up. The solution is to use a rich text editor, save it as HTML and display it directly.